# Copy or clone rows from SQL Server table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

Here is my code after modifications, things seems working fine but I am receiving an error on `_db.SubmitChanges();`

Error is

> Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use.

Code:

```
foreach (tblCourseNeededHours record in thisTable)
{
            tblCourseNeededHours newCNHR = new tblCourseNeededHours();
            newCNHR.Semester = a_semesterToOrganize;
            newCNHR.AssignToInstituteAdministrator = false;
            newCNHR.Freezed = false;

            _db.tblCourseNeededHours.InsertOnSubmit(newCNHR);
}

// submit all the changes
_db.SubmitChanges();
```

I am using MVC 2.0 and SQL Server. I have a table called `tblCourses`.

I want to select rows based on some selection criteria, then I want to append these rows to `tblCourse`.

Do I need to create a temporary table `tmpCourse` and to fill in these selected rows and then append them those back to `tblCourse`? Or can I do it without temporary table?

Any suggestion, post link ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can just do something like:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tblCourse(list of columns)
    SELECT (list of columns)
    FROM dbo.tblCourse
    WHERE (your condition here.....)
```

Of course, the list of columns must match, e.g. you have to have the same number of columns, and the same datatypes. Also, you cannot insert values into e.g. `IDENTITY` or computed columns.

**Update:** to do this in Linq-to-SQL, you'd have to have an entity that can represent your data in some way. Then:

- select the data from your existing database into a `List<Entity>` (or whatever your entity is really called)
- create new objects (entities) based on those retrieved - change your properties as needed
- insert those entities back into the data context
- save the changes.

Something along the lines of this code snippet (here I have a table `countries` which has an `ISOCode` and a `CountryName` for some countries; I'm selecting a few, and creating new ones based on those retrieved, adding those new ones to the Linq-to-SQL `DataContext` and saving in the end):

```
// create and use the Linq-to-SQL DataContext
using (LinqSampleDataContext ctx = new LinqSampleDataContext())
{
    // select some data
    IQueryable<country> existingCountries = ctx.countries.Where(c => c.CountryID < 100);

    // loop over selected data - create new entities based on data retrieved
    foreach (country c in existingCountries)
    {
        country newCountry = new country();
        newCountry.CountryName = c.CountryName;
        newCountry.ISOCode = "X" + c.ISOCode.Substring(1);

        // add new entities to DataContext
        ctx.countries.InsertOnSubmit(newCountry);
    }

    // submit all the changes
    ctx.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: I am using Linq to SQL, Can somebody help me to translate above mentioned query in LINQ to SQL. I am at very beginner level in this case

Comment: please check the update code, i am receving error on a last line of the code, the error is   "Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use."